# Laravel 4 share session / cookie outside the laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-4

I am using laravel with core php . My admin panel is on laravel and store site is on core php. My project structure is like :

```
index.php
test.php
laravel-admin/  -- laravel
```

Now I just want to detect wether the laravel session is active on store or not. I tried session , cookies and all but all failed. Here is what i have tried :

Using this code in laravel admin

```
setcookie('admin_id', 1,0,'/');
```

And this is who i am trying to access in core php :

```
echo $_COOKIE['admin_id']
```

All i have tried but its totally random behavior. not getting cookie everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `setcookie()` is the expiration. As you set to 0 it will be deleted each time you leave your session.

If you want your cookie to be alive for, say, 3 days add 259200 (3 * 24 * 3600) to the current timestamp :
`setcookie('admin_id', 1, time()+259200, '/');`